# Math Notation in facet_wrap() Label Not Working

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

My data:

```
plot_df <- 
structure(list(model = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Full", 
"Point Differential"), class = "factor"), measure = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("AIC", "R^2", "Number of Predictors"
), class = "factor"), value = c(266.666394197942, 303.321585856894, 
0.851698145309359, 0.713883491646847, 10, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I made the following plot using the data:

```
ggplot(plot_df, aes(y=value, x=model, fill=model)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~measure, scales='free') +
  labs(title='Model Comparison', x='', y='Value', fill='Model') +
  geom_text(aes(label=round(value,2)),vjust=1.25) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

[image]

The second `facet_wrap()` pane has the title `R^2`, but it is not in math notation. I have tried using `labeller=label_parsed()`, but it doesn't work. Additionally, I have tried using the `latex2exp` package, but that doesn't work either. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is `labeller=label_parsed`, not `labeller=label_parsed()`.

But in addition, you have to replace the white spaces with `~`:

```
levels(plot_df$measure)[3] <- "Number~of~Predictors"
ggplot(plot_df, aes(y=value, x=model, fill=model)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~measure, scales='free', labeller = label_parsed) +
  ......
```

[image]